# Denormalize table in clickhouse with sql query

Tags: sql, denormalization, clickhouse

The source table has the format

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src_table (
    str_1 String,
    str_2 String,
    metric_1 UInt64,
    metric_2 UInt8
) ENGINE = Log
```

the column to be denormalized is str_2
and the denormalized table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS denorm_table (
    dt Date,
    str_1 String,
    attr_1 UInt64,
    attr_2 UInt64,
    ......
    attr_1000 UInt64,
    attr_1001 UInt8,
    attr_1002 UInt8,
    .....
    attr_2000 UInt8
) ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY (dt) ORDER BY (dt, str_1) SETTINGS index_granularity=8192
```

Assume column str_2 has 1000 distinct values (1 ... 1000) and that

attr_1 is the value of column metric_1 when str_2 equals 1,

attr_2 is the value of column metric_1 when str_2 equals 1,

.....

attr_1001 is the value of column metric_2 when str_2 equals 1

...

The denormalize query is:

```
 INSERT INTO denorm_table        
(dt, user, attr_1, attr_2, ..., attr_1000, attr_1001, attr_2000)
 SELECT 
'2018-11-01' as dt,
str_1,
arrayElement( groupArray(metric_1), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '1') ) as attr_1,
arrayElement( groupArray(metric_1), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '2') ) as attr_2,
......
arrayElement( groupArray(metric_1), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '1000') ) as attr_1000,
arrayElement( groupArray(metric_2), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '1001') ) as attr_1001,
.....
arrayElement( groupArray(metric_1), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '2000') ) as attr_2000
FROM src_table
WHERE str_2 in ('1', '2', .....)
GROUP BY str_1
```

For 750 values of column str_2 (1502 columns in denormalized table) the query works with no issues.

But when the number of columns of denormalized table are 2002 (and the corresponding str_2 values 1000) I have a **socket.timeout: timed out** ERROR

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 119, in execute
columnar=columnar
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 192, in process_ordinary_query
columnar=columnar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 42, in receive_result
return result.get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/result.py", line 39, in get_result
for packet in self.packet_generator:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 54, in packet_generator
packet = self.receive_packet()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/client.py", line 68, in receive_packet
packet = self.connection.receive_packet()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 331, in receive_packet
packet.type = packet_type = read_varint(self.fin)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/reader.py", line 38, in read_varint
i = _read_one(f)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/reader.py", line 23, in _read_one
c = f.read(1)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Is there a setting in client/server that would eliminate the problem?

---

From logs

```
2018.12.04 22:49:26.755926 [ 36 ] {} <Trace> SystemLog (system.query_thread_log): Flushing system log
2018.12.04 22:49:26.756233 [ 139 ] {821ce7ea-94b7-4675-96f5-feccb31b0ebe} <Error> executeQuery: Code: 32, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof, e.what() = DB::Exception (from [::1]:52224) (in query:
```

**========= EDIT =========**

I modified query like below (@johey) and the error did not happen again:

`WHERE modulo(sipHash64(str_1), 20) = 0` is used for splitting data in groups
instead of running the query for all values in column str_1

```
INSERT INTO dst_table (....)
SELECT
    arrayElement(metric_1_array, indexOf(str_2_array, '1') ) as attr_1,
    arrayElement(metric_1_array, indexOf(str_2_array, '2') ) as attr_2,
    ......
    arrayElement(metric_2_array, indexOf(str_2_array, '1') ) as attr_1001,
    ......
FROM (
    SELECT
        str_1,
        groupArray(metric_1) metric_1_array,
        groupArray(metric_2) metric_2_array,
        groupArray(str_2) str_2_array
    FROM src_table
    WHERE modulo(sipHash64(str_1), 20) = 0
    AND str_2 in ('1', '2', ......)
    GROUP BY str_1
)
```

Comment: Probably this doesn't fix it, but maybe you could shorten the query a bit like this: `INSERT INTO denorm_table (...) SELECT 
'2018-11-01' as dt,
str_1,
arrayElement(metric1, indexOf(str2, '1') ) as attr_1,
arrayElement(metric1, indexOf(str2, '2') ) as attr_2,
...
FROM (
SELECT user, str_1, groupArray(metric_1) metric1, groupArray(metric_2) metric2, groupArray(str_2) str2
FROM src_table
WHERE str_2 in ('1', '2', .....) ) s
GROUP BY user`

Comment: Stupid remark maybe (because I don't understand what you're trying to do), but isn't `indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '1')` also going to give a "positive negative" result when str_2 equals e.g. 1001 ? That's not something you want is it?

Comment: This example is not self-contained. What's the `user` column?

Comment: `user` is `str_1` column

Comment: `arrayElement( groupArray(metric_1), indexOf(groupArray(str_2), '1') )` ---> I want to retrieve value of metric_1 column that corresponds to the value '1' of column str_2 (make the 2 columns array and use the elements of 2nd array for indexing the 1st one) @johey

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have blown up the AST parser. There are two settings that cap the size of the input AST trees : `max_ast_elements` and `max_expanded_ast_elements`. You can try lifting them and see if it helps.

Here is another way to achieve this denormalization process,

```
SELECT
    arrayStringConcat(arrayConcat(['2018-11-01', str_1], arraySlice(groupArray(toString(metric_1)), 1, 1000), arraySlice(groupArray(toString(metric_2)), 1001, 1000)), ',')
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM src_table
    WHERE toUInt64(str_2) BETWEEN 1 AND 2000
    ORDER BY toUInt64(str_2)
)
GROUP BY str_1
INTO OUTFILE 'xxx.csv'
```

Then loading that csv data file into `denorm_table`.

## Update

After this [PR](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/pull/3761) gets merged, you can achieve server side ETL like this:

```
INSERT INTO denorm_table
SELECT
    arrayStringConcat(arrayConcat(['2018-11-01', str_1], arraySlice(groupArray(toString(metric_1)), 1, 1000), arraySlice(groupArray(toString(metric_2)), 1001, 1000)), ',')
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM src_table
    WHERE toUInt64(str_2) BETWEEN 1 AND 2000
    ORDER BY toUInt64(str_2)
)
GROUP BY str_1
FORMAT CSV
```